# Specify Universal Firebase FCM Icons for Web and Android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble with something when trying to implement FCM for Web and Android.
On the Web, I specify a url for my notifications Icon, like:

```
"notification": {
    "title": "New Notification!",
    "body": "omg so important",
    "icon": "images/notification_icon.png",
    "click_action": "https://mydomain/someurl"
}
```

But then if this would break on android right? Which needs something like

```
"icon": "ic_launcher"
```

Also, the click action I guess is different too?

Does this mean we need to send separate notifications for web and android?
Thanks